# talend - lost few records not inserted in database

Tags: talend

I am very new to talend and I have been struggling with this since two weeks now

I need to diagnose a problem happening with a job (see picture)

When I execute the job I see on the screen it says 1000 rows committed to the database but when you go to the database there is fewer records

Is there a way to tell why there are fewer records committed to the database then what it said on the screen ?

[image: job]

tmap:

[image: tmap]

Comment: Thanks for adding your question here. To help you, I'd need to get more details. First, would you know the version number as well as the product you are using? Also, I might need other screenshots to get a better view of what's happening with your job. Would you have a TMap configuration screenshot and a screenshot with stats? That would help us a lot! Thanks,
T Data.

Comment: thanks a lot,its Talend Open Studio for Data Integration 5, I just updated my question with tMap screenshot,How can I get stats?

Comment: "Look if there is any output at the run panel. Its like an Java console. Maybe there are problems with unique indexes, duplicate primary keys or the schema of the input table." from [Janine](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1662910/janine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After talking to a few colleagues, I got some interesting answers. About your question, you could add a reject link after tMysqlOutput to see if it has any records.

For example: tMysqlInput--main--tMap--out1--tMysqlOutput---reject--tLogRow

Hope this helps! T Data.

Comment: Thanks I've done it, I can see the number of rows rejected when i execute,but I dont know how can I see the actual rows and the reason of rejection

Comment: OK great! Now, what you can do, is look in the Run view under the work space to find the rejected rows.

Comment: Thanks.
For the records,In order for the tLogRow to work,I unchecked "Extend insert" in advanced setting from component tab and checked "debug mode" and "tStatCatcher stats"

Comment: Now the problem is that even the input number of rows isnt the same as the number of rows I have in my database, and when I run the job I get a red square on the tMap saying error,but I dont know how to identify this error

Comment: Mmmh... what you could do is go on the TalendForge forum (http://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewforum.php?id=2), where you could ask your question to the entire community. There are many members, more technical than I am, able to help out on these type questions. They will be able to clearly identify where the issue is coming from. You can post a message, with a summary of what you've already mentioned here. I think your question will clearly benefit the entire community. Best! Talend Data

Comment: Great, I saw the other post! Seems like you are getting plenty of help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

i think you should check the tMap join type for all lookups. By changing lookup type you will get desired output. see attached image.[image]